# Carb adjustment on carb where L and H aren't marked

Tags: carburetor, small-engine

I'm working on a string trimmer currently whose adjustment screws are not labeled - or the labels have worn off with time.  :)  For reference, the carb is a Zama.  It *seems* to me that there is a standard protocol on which adjustment screw is which on diaphragm carburettors.

From my memory, the `L` screw (low-speed jet) is closer to the engine block, and the `H` screw is usually closer to the air filter.  Can anyone confirm or debunk this?

Comment: I know you're trying to make this generic, but really if you'd like specific help here, giving us a carb and/or engine model number, plus the make of the trimmer you're working on, we'd be able to answer your question a lot easier. Pictures would be an added bonus :o)